# Scanning an array for length of longest sub-array divisible by 3

Tags: java, arrays, modulus, sub-array

I'm writing a program that scans an array and produces the length of the longest sub-array containing elements whose sum is divisible by 3. I have worked using the concept from another question here, using the prefix sum concept - scanning first and last sums that by modolu 3 give out 0,1, 2, calculating the difference between each set and returning the biggest one of the three.

I decided to test it using a random array generator. 90% of the time it works but in others it misses correct answer by a few numbers.
Any idea what's wrong?

I've included a tester that includes a non-efficient method that does the same thing. Picture included:

[image: Picture of outcome]

Output:

> 84|4|94|27|85|10|87|11|66|34|66|42|26|65|12|93|14|
>
> array size is: 17
>
> Bad What: 15
>
> My What: 13

Code:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.Random;

 public class Q1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] a = new int[rand.nextInt(100)];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
            System.out.print(a[i] + "|");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("array size is: " + a.length);
        System.out.println("Bad What: " + badWhat(a));
        System.out.println("My What: " + what(a));
    }

    public static int what(int[] a) {
        int sumLeft = 0, sumRight = 0;
        int zero, one, two;
        int firstZero = 0, firstOne = 0, firstTwo = 0, lastZero = 0, lastOne = 0, lastTwo = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sumLeft += negMod(a[i])%3;
            sumRight += negMod(a[a.length - 1 - i]%3);
            if ((sumLeft) % 3 == 0)
                firstZero = i;
                if ((sumRight) % 3 == 0)
                    lastZero = i;
                if ((sumLeft) % 3 == 1)
                    firstOne = i;
                if ((sumRight) % 3 == 1)
                    lastOne = i;
                if ((sumLeft) % 3 == 2)
                    firstTwo = i;
                if ((sumRight) % 3 == 2)
                    lastTwo = i;
            }
        firstOne++;
        firstTwo++;
        zero = lastZero - firstZero + 1;
        one = lastOne - firstOne;
        two = lastTwo - firstTwo;
        int result = max(max(zero, one), two);
        if (firstZero +1 > result)
            result = ++firstZero;
        return result;
    }

    public static int negMod (int a)
    {
        if (a<0)
        {
            return (a+3);
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static int f (int[] a, int low, int high)
    {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = low; i<=high; i++)
            res += a[i];
        return res;
    }

    public static int badWhat (int[] a)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i =0; i< a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++) {
                int c = f(a, i, j);
                if (c % 3 == 0) {
                    if (j - i + 1 > temp)
                        temp = j - i + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"90% of the time it works but in others it misses correct answer by a few numbers"* - post the sample input / output / expected output tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've edited the post.

Comment: Is there *any* reason you included them as screenshots and not as actual code? How is someone supposed ti plug the screenshot into their code and figure out why your code is misbehaving?

Comment: I've included the output into the text, No need to get angry, it's my first time asking a question here.

Comment: @Jamaico: unless someone is using aggressive words here, don't read too much into people's tone. If it steps over a line substantially you can flag it for a moderator, but otherwise just bear in mind that high-rep users keep on seeing the same posting problems, and they (we) would love to make Stack Overflow more efficient by helping people to get questions reasonably right/answerable in the first edit.

Comment: Not posting code as images has been a thing for as long as copy+paste has been a thing, and that guideline would apply to any site on the internet offering code assistance. Images are not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen-readers. Hope that helps! `:-)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious mistake is that instead of `sumLeft += negMod(a[i] % 3);` you have `sumLeft += negMod(a[i])%3;`.

It appears you have a lot of problems in your algorithm. First of all, in `sumRight` you should contain sum of elements from the first to the current one, but what you contained was sum from the current to the last one. So, it was just a good luck that your solution worked for some tests.

Secondly, you should find the first subarray with a particular modulo and the last one. So, you don't need to overwrite the value once it is found.

This should work:

```
public static int what(int[] a) {
    if (a.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int sumLeft = 0, sumRight = 0;
    for (int el : a) {
        sumRight += el % 3;
    }
    sumRight = negMod(sumRight % 3);

    int firstZero = a.length, firstOne = a.length, firstTwo = a.length,
            lastZero = -1, lastOne = -1, lastTwo = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length + 1; i++) {
        if (sumLeft % 3 == 0 && firstZero == a.length)
            firstZero = i;
        if (sumRight % 3 == 0 && lastZero == -1)
            lastZero = a.length - 1 - i;
        if (sumLeft % 3 == 1 && firstOne == a.length)
            firstOne = i;
        if (sumRight % 3 == 1 && lastOne == -1)
            lastOne = a.length - 1 - i;
        if (sumLeft % 3 == 2 && firstTwo == a.length)
            firstTwo = i;
        if (sumRight % 3 == 2 && lastTwo == -1)
            lastTwo = a.length - 1 - i;
        sumLeft += negMod(a[min(i, a.length - 1)] % 3);
        sumRight = negMod(sumRight - a[max(a.length - 1 - i, 0)] % 3);
    }
    int zero = lastZero - firstZero + 1;
    int one = lastOne - firstOne + 1;
    int two = lastTwo - firstTwo + 1;
    Integer[] options = new Integer[]{zero, one, two, 0};
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(options));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It decreased the number of mistakes but there are still problems with it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see my main problem was not being prepared for the concept that a modulo (1,2,0) can appear only once or non at all.
You're the man!

Comment: @ A. Yurchenko
There is a problem when you enter a single element array not divisible by 3, I.E. 58|
array size is: 1
Bad What: 0
My What: 1

Comment: @Jamaico - I edited my answer, check  it again. There was an issue with wrong-chosen initial values

Comment: What's wrong with adding  
if ((a.length == 1) && ( a[0]%3 != 0))
            {
                return 0;
            }

Comment: @Jamaico - Nothing. Just another way to solve the problem. Anyway, I guess I answered your question